# require в обычном JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Какие способы есть для клиентской части, чтобы разбить большой код на несколько частей, как с помощью require в node.js?

Comment: require есть и в клиентской части (как отдельный компонент)

Comment: Это [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) сам модуль, [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/152833/) на Habrahabr о том как пользоваться

Comment: Можно было уж из этой статьи сюда что-то написать для понимая   с указанием ссылки на источник....не такая она там и большая, чтоб ссылкой оставлять

Comment: Синтаксис `require` в node.js и в Require.js в общем случае различается. В статье по ссылке это четко видно.